# Why does my CodeBlocks app keep failing to execute code?

Tags: c, ide, codeblocks

Just started to learn programming language and now I'm learning C. When I run this simple code, my CodeBlocks app keeps failing to execute the code. Here is the code I wrote:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello world!\n");
    printf("Hello world!\n");
    printf("Hello world!\n");
    printf("Hello world!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

This is the result after I clicked the run button:

```
Hello world!

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.016 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Any idea why does my CodeBlocks app keep failing to execute code?

Comment: Run the program from the command line. It should run fine. If so, it has nothing to do with the program, and everything to do with your IDE.

Answer (score 2):

You should compile, then run the app, for a shortcut, press F9.
Press this[image]

or this:

[image]